# How to define closure type to send into thread safetly

Tags: rust, thread-safety, closures

I'm trying to send a closure into a thread to process like:

```
fn spawn<F>(work_load: F) where F: FnMut() {
    let builder = Builder::new();
    let handler = builder.spawn(move || {
        // Before process
        work_load();
        // After process
    }).unwrap();
}
```

But I'm getting an error:
**`F` cannot be sent between threads safely**

In a high overview I need to do this (code compiles):

```
let closure = || env_variable.to_string();

thread::spawn(move || {
    // before closure
    closure();
    // after closure
});
```

How I can define `F` so I can send it into thread, considering I need to capture environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a look at [`thread::spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) or [`thread::Builder::spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/struct.Builder.html#method.spawn), you will see that it has the signature

```rust
pub fn spawn<F, T>(f: F) -> JoinHandle<T> 
where
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
    F: Send + 'static,
    T: Send + 'static,
```

This means that both the thread closure `f` and its return value must implement the [`Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Send.html) trait (i.e. be sendable across threads) and have a `'static` lifetime (i.e. not have any borrows with a non-static lifetime).

A closure will be `Send` if all of its captured variables are. It will also be `'static` if all of its captured variables are and all captured variables are moved into the closure (which is what the `move` keyword does).

Since the only captured variable in your closure is `work_load`, you need to ensure that `work_load` is both `Send` and `'static`:

```rust
fn spawn<F>(work_load: F)
where
    F: FnMut() + Send + 'static
//               ^---.---^
//                   \_ add these constraints to F
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll take a look on those `+` as I'm learning Rust and didn't know about that type composition or intersection.

Comment: Note: Parameters to the closure also need to be `Send + 'static`. `Send` is necessary because things must be sent beyond thread boundaries. You can wrap things that aren't `Send` in  an `Arc`, for example, to work around this limitation (there are other ways). The `'static` lifetime is needed because a thread could detach and live even longer than the main thread.